# passing base-type to method

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

If I have two classes, which are derived from a base-class, how can I write a generic method, that can manipulate the inherited properties of both classes, so I do not need to write two methods...

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
}

public class State:BaseClass
{
    public string StateName{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class City:BaseClass
{
    public string TownName { get; set; }
    public string someOtherProperty{ get; set; }

}
```

THE "generic" Method:

```
public string Slugify( ?????BaseClass???? record)
{
    return record.slug = "...return...something...";
}
```

invoked like:

```
string a = Slugify(my_State_object); <--- not working
string b = Slugify(my_City_object);  <--- not working
```

Thank you!

EDIT:
State and City are EF-CodeFirst Classes. Initially both had Id and slug - fields.

then I made these into a base class, as I have those in both (and other) tables.

I want a method that returns slug like:

```
public string Slugify(string p, System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.BaseRecords> dbSet){ return ...}
```

called like

```
Slugify(text, my_State_object);
```

as well as

```
Slugify(otherText, my_City_object);
```

both calls give me a "...some invalid arguments..." error.

Sorry, this is translated from german VS2010

Comment: Why can't you just use BaseClass as the type of the parameter?

Comment: Please elaborate, does the Slugify method require access to the derived class properties? At the moment it only access slug, which is a member of the base class and thus, perfectly legal.

Comment: Define "not working" and we can possibly help you.

Comment: Are you getting a compilation error or are you just getting back unexpected results?

Comment: Please don't use tags in the title: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: sorry... "not working" means - "invalid arguments for overloaded method"

Comment: Ok, now there's more context. Your `Slugify` methods' signatures does not match what you're passing it at all.

Answer (score 6):

You already gave the answer:

```
public string Slugify(BaseClass record)
{
    return record.slug = "...return...something...";
}
```

The issue is that your BaseClass should be as accessible as its children. Make it public and it will be fine:

```
public abstract class BaseClass ...
```

Comment: Whilst that's correct, there should be a compile time error in OP's code. Their abstract base class is less accessible than the children.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your `abstract` base class is not public and so it is less accessible than its children. Change it to this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
}
```

The rest of the code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the assumption that how you generate a slug is different for each type.  `State` would be based upon the `StateName` property, while `City` would use the `TownName` property.

I think this might be a better approach:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string Slug { get; }
}

public class State:BaseClass
{
    public string StateName{ get; set; }
    public abstract string Slug 
    {
        get 
        {
            return Regex.Replace(StateName, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '-');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what keeps you from simply accessing the properties of the baseclass?

```
Class A
{
    public string Rawr {get; set;}
}

Class B : A
{
    public string Rawr2 { get { return Rawr; } set { Rawr = value; } }
}

var b = new B();
b.Rawr = "asdf"

Console.WriteLine(b.Rawr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass();
baseClass.slug = "initial value";
Console.WriteLine(baseClass.slug); // displays "initial value"
Slugify(baseClass);
Console.WriteLine(baseClass.slug); // displays "...return...something..."

State state = new State();
state.slug = "initial value";
Console.WriteLine(state.slug); // displays "initial value"
Slugify(state);
Console.WriteLine(state.slug); // displays "...return...something..."
```

You should see that your Slugify method can already change properties in the BaseClass and State classes, as long as you get rid of the question marks:

```
public string Slugify(BaseClass record)  
{
    return record.slug = "...return...something...";  
}
```